# Compare two php array ranges in Wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a formidable pro form field set up with a filter to test the field when someone types in a number. If the number is in the acceptable range (in this case 200-300) then the form will submit, if not, the form will report an error. I need to set the filter up so that it compares two or more range sets instead of just one, but I don't understand how to set up a second or even a third range. With two or three, array ranges to compare, it needs to function the same.

```
add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'my_custom_validation', 10, 3);
function my_custom_validation($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value){
  if($posted_field->id == 92){         
    if(!in_array($posted_value, range(200,300) ) ){ 
      //if it doesn't match up, add an error:
    $errors['field'. $posted_field->id] = 'You have entered an invalid number!';
    }         
  }
  return $errors;
}
```

I have tried setting up two if(!in_array... statements, but I don't know PHP well enough to get the syntax for the array range comparison right. Please help me understand how I can make this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to separate your checks with `&&`, the "and" syntax:

```
if(!in_array($posted_value, range(200,300) ) && 
   !in_array($posted_value, range(400,500) ) && 
   !in_array($posted_value, range(900,999) ) ){
```

This way, if the number given is not in the first range AND not in the second range, etc. the error case will be true. If it is in any of the ranges, the error case will be false.